# Graph data in ganglia that is only received periodically without zeroing out

Tags: rrdtool, ganglia

I'm wondering how to fix graphing gaps in a custom metric for my companies application that we retreive every five minutes via cronjob. The cronjob collects the data and puts it into rrds and sends to ganglia for aggregation and collection. Currently, this graph will spike upon receiving the new data, then show zero out until the collection job runs again and a new value has been generated, which distorts the average values as well as the longer timeframe graphs (since all the zero values reduce the average over time).

How do I get ganglia to set a ttl for a counter metric so that it doesn't graph zero between metric collection runs?

Comment: https://github.com/pcpiela/ganglia-web/commit/033f603f68a88bab1a60a9c62618ec0c335840d3

Comment: this code is already present in my graph.php and inspect_graph.php